# "Does Not Contain" Function VBA

Tags: vba, excel, syntax

I am looking for a way to add a "Does not contain" criteria to a string. I want it to find a string that is Numeric, has a length of 9 characters, and does not contain a period "."

I've looked on the web but just found filters for a whole worksheet, or filters, or arrays, not for doesn't contain one specific character.

This part works:

```
If IsNumeric(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) _
    And Len(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) = 9 Then
```

But I would like it to say:

```
If IsNumeric(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) _
     And Len(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) = 9 _
           and Doesnotcontain "." Then
```

What would be the proper syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Instr() function:

```
If IsNumeric(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) _
     And Len(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)) = 9 _
           and Instr(Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10), ".") = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

I note that your example is not looking for a "word" but rather examining a string of up to 10 characters, and ensuring there is exactly nine (9) digits.  If that is what you want, then the following should work:

**EDIT:** Simplify the code

```
S = Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10)

If S Like "#########" Then
          ... Your Routine ...
End If
```

or even:

```
If Left(Right(wordDoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text, 11), 10) Like _
    "#########" Then
          ... Your Routine ...
End If
```

The general case of finding a "does not contain" is to use the InStr function, test for the string, and look for a return value of zero (0). Although sometimes, if the "does not contain" value is complex, use of regular expressions should be considered.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This does work but the above response just fits better where I want it to go. Thank you for responding!